# Скачивание файла с сайта с помощью Python

Tags: python, requests

пытаюсь скачать файл сформированный файл товаров, с сайта https://propartner.ru, с помощью get, так же пробовал с помощью wget и urlib.
Post формирует id файла, проверяя через инспектор id правильный.

```
urlload = 'https://www.propartner.ru/user/product/download-export- 
excel-file?key='
urlvigruz = 'https://www.propartner.ru/user/product/export-excel'
respvigruz = session.post(urlvigruz, {
     'ExportExcelForm[company_id]': '12345',
     'ExportExcelForm[type]': '0',
     'ExportExcelForm[type]': '1',
     'ExportExcelForm[type]': '0',
     'ExportExcelForm[rubrics]': ''})
vigruzJson = respvigruz.json()
vigruzTovar = vigruzJson['key']
print(vigruzTovar)
d = session.get(urlload+vigruzTovar)
```

Во время выполнения просто получаю долгую загрузку и 504, хотя вставляя ссылку в браузере скачивание начинается автоматически, пробовал в get передать напрямую ссылку без переменных результат такой же. Уже всё перепробовал так и не могу получить файл, при попытки записи просто создается пустой файл.

Comment: content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Тип в инспекторе если поможет

Comment: в session авторизован, через post загружать файлы получается.

Comment: Приведите минимальный и воспроизводимый пример, ваш вырванный кусок вряд-ли поможет.

Comment: Или вам просто объяснить что значит ошибка 504?

Comment: Нет, просто не понимаю как получить файл через get, ибо запрос просто не чего не выдает, но по открытии ссылки в браузере начинается автоматическая загрузка, пытался читать get и записывать его в файл но файл пустой ибо видимо сам запрос не чего не отдает

Comment: В куске, я показываю как отправляю get, по сути другой код это просто авторизация и передача сессии в этот метод

Comment: Алексей, по правилам ресурса, вы должны привести пример (код) который приводит к ошибке, что бы желающий помочь вам человек, скопировал его (код)  вставил в свою среду разработки и запустил, без каких-либо телодвижений с правкой 1000 строк кода. Иначе вы не дождётесь адекватной помощи. Как бы вы сами попытались решить свой вопрос?

Comment: "Нет, просто не понимаю как получить файл через get, ибо запрос просто не чего не выдает, но по открытии ссылки в браузере начинается автоматическая загрузка, пытался читать get и записывать его в файл но файл пустой ибо видимо сам запрос не чего не отдает" - исходя из этого уже можно понять что вы запрос делаете не так как ваш браузер, верно?

Comment: Да вот что странно я прям копировал ссылку и вставлял в запрос, результат такой же

Comment: Вы не поняли, вот допустим у вас есть объект session, пожалуйста распечатайте user-agent из session.

Comment: 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'

Comment: То есть вы сами добавили user-agent так?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена надо записывать файл по частям, чанками

Comment: Отправлять или скачивать? Желательно добавить код, как именно реализовали.

Comment: while True:
            with open(file,"wb") as xl:
                r = session.get(URL, allow_redirects=True, stream = True)
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    xl.write(chunk)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                break

Comment: Добавьте код в сам ответ